# Code coverage for AuraHandledException in catch blcok

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public with sharing class ContactCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<AccountContactRelation> getRelatedContacts(String accId){
        List<AccountContactRelation> result = New List<AccountContactRelation>();
    
        try{ 
            result = [Select id, Contact.Name, Contact.Phone, Contact.GA_Contact_Role__c from AccountContactRelation where AccountId =: accId]; 
        }   
        catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return result; 
    }
```

}

Test class:

```
@IsTest
public class ContactCtrl_Test {

    @IsTest
    private static void getRelatedContacts() {
        Account account = getAccount();
        Database.insert(account);

        Test.startTest();
        try {
            ContactCtrl.getRelatedContacts(account.Id);
        }
        catch(exception e) {

        }  
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

The above test class I wrote is not covering the    `catch(Exception ex){throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());}` line. What should I write to cover that Exception in catch block?
Anyone can please suggest me
`

Comment: Don't strive for 100% coverage. I never do. Why should this SOQL ever fail? because of access issues, sure. But do you really want to complicate your tests to simulate no permission user calls. I say dont do it.

Comment: That `try` block literally cannot cause an exception. Just remove the `try`/ `catch` entirely.

Comment: Strong disagree about 100% coverage.

Comment: Hi @RobertSösemann, I am not trying to get 100%. We have many more methods where exception block is not covering. So because of that coverage is coming less than 75%